# View blocked address from sshguard

Tags: ssh, iptables

How can I view all the addresses that sshguard has blocked to iptables?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SSH Guard have to has it's own chain in `iptables` called `sshguard` and you can view rules in this chain by:

```
iptables -nvL sshguard
```

More info on setup sshguard for iptables [here](https://www.sshguard.net/docs/setup/#netfilter-iptables)

Comment: The link you posted is dead

Comment: I've just fixed the link.

Comment: If you want to remove one of the blocked addresses use `iptables -nvL sshguard --line-numbers` to get the line number and then `iptables -D sshguard {line-number}` to remove the specific line.

Comment: I just got the error `/usr/sbin/sshguard: 83: [: iptables: unexpected operator` but I found out, it was because I accidently put `sshguard` before the whole command again